# Как правильно сделать ЧПУ?

Tags: url, .htaccess, php, чпу

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста, как грамотно организовать ЧПУ на сайте. Сейчас делаю так:

```
...ru/blog/article/statja
```

и разбираю эту строку на массивы explode(/), где за первым слэшем идет контроллер, а дальше идут пары ключ\значение. В поисковиках ссылки отображаются так:

```
http://...../blog/article/statja - ссылка на сайте
[http://...../][блог/][article/статья] В квадратные скобки взял, то на что делит поисковик мои ссылки. Т.е. это он выделяет в одну ссылку [article/статья] - не очень то красиво выглядит.
```

Хотя, сейчас посмотрел, яндекс отображает правильно, т.е. *сайт / блог / статья* (спустя четыре месяца). Но суть вопроса то не в поисковиках, самому хочется организовать URL грамотно.

Хотелось бы сделать так: (Чтобы стер одно слово, открылась другая страничка, а не ошибка вылетела)

```
...ru/blog/statja
```

Все казалось бы просто, но у меня возникла сложность вот с чем: ссылки то могут быть разными:

```
...ru/blog/statja
...ru/blog/category/nazvanie-categorii
...ru/blog/page/25
```

т.е. **Есть ссылки которым все таки необходима пара КЛЮЧ\ЗНАЧЕНИЕ, так как же обрабатывать такую строку?**

И еще попутный вопрос. Если я хочу сделать URL такого вида:

```
...ru/blog/statja
...ru/blog/nazvanie-categorii
```

Получается нужно создать отдельную табличку в базе данных, которая будет хранить ЧПУ и принадлежность к категории или к статье, тогда я смогу избежать дубликатов и четко буду понимать что откуда брать, верно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Одна из проблем такого подхода, что при большом кол-ве статей, названия могут повторяться и тогда будет трабла, решение название делать в виде - "id-news_name", и как раз вам тогда будет легко понимать, если начинается с числа - новость, если с буквы - категория. А так ваши суждения вроде верны и приемлемы, Вам осталось только реализовать.

Comment: Спасибо! Я кстати делал без id перед статьей, а при добавлении в базу проверял на уникальность, если ЧПУ с таким названием уже есть, то добавляю ему цифру, например: staja-1. Я думаю что в таком варианте плюс тоже есть, в тех заголовках которые не дублируются не будет лишних цифр.

Comment: А по поводу основного вопроса не подскажите? Как же все таки распарсить строку, когда ссылка выглядит так: ...ru/blog/nazvanie-categorii/page/25/desc/. Т.е. когда в ссылке могут содержаться и ОДИНОЧНЫЕ (blog,categoria,desc) параметры и пары КЛЮЧ\Значение(page = 25)

Comment: единственное что вам нажо сделать, чтобы в названии новости символ "/" заменялся на что нибудь, на нижнее подчеркивание например, потом explode разбивать, а все остальное как говориться дело техники. передают обычно ОДИНОЧНЫЕ параметры, а если нужно ключ-значение, делайте через другой символ. Пример: http:...ru/my_blog/page=25/desc
Потом через explode разбиваете по / и потом каждую переменную пытаетесь найти структуру ключ-значение.